# Synthetic projective definition of cubic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, conic-sections

In a synthetic (Pappian) projective plane, one can define a conic in various clever ways not referring to coordinates.  For instance, if $f$ is a projectivity from the pencil of lines through a point $A$ to the pencil of lines through another point $B$, then the locus of intersections $m \cap f(m)$ is a conic (which is nondegenerate if $f$ is not a perspectivity), and all conics are obtaned in this way.

Is there any analogous way to define curves of higher order?  Say cubics, for definiteness?

Comment: There are many such constructions for *rational* (singular) curves, e.g. the strophoid, see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strophoid). My intuition is that such geometric constructions will always produce rational curves, though I don't know how to justify it.

Comment: @abx The description of the strophoid in the Wikipedia article involves distance, which doesn't exist in a projective plane.  Is there a version of it that doesn't use distances?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a "classical" fact that any nonsingular plane cubic curve $C$ can be projectively generated by means of a pencil of lines and a pencil of conics.

The starting point of the construction is the observation that the lines defined by any $g_2^1$ on $C$ all pass through the same point $p$ of $C$, that following Sylvester is called the *coresidual* point.

Now, take four points $q_1, \ldots, q_4$ on $C$, such that any three of them are not  collinear. Let $p \in C$ be the coresidual point with respect to the $g_2^1$ on $C$ cut by the pencils of conics through $q_1, \ldots, q_4$. Therefore such a pencil of conics and the pencil of lines through $p$ projectively generate $C$.

All of this is explained in the paper by N. Fraser *[Kötter's synthetic geometry of algebraic curves](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayFulltext?type=1&fid=3146652&jid=PEM&volumeId=7&issueId=-1&aid=3131388&bodyId=&membershipNumber=&societyETOCSession=)*, Proceedings of the Edinburgh Mathematical Society **7**, 46–61 (1888). However, the language is rather old-fashioned so the article is not easy to read nowadays.

A modern treatment  can be found in Dolgachev's book *Classical Algebraic Geometry*, Section 3.3 ([this](https://books.google.it/books?id=g9GLXmR9qg0C&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq=projective%20generation%20of%20cubics&source=bl&ots=9yrG2MNEYv&sig=Xn9pePQ98v8ogYUuPbV7IAGcPEI&hl=it&sa=X&ei=MkA3VYSfFpHoaMO_gcAN&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=projective%20generation%20of%20cubics&f=false) is the googlebook link).

Comment: What is a $g^1_2$?

Comment: @MikeShulman - this is some particular kind of divisor, IIRC...

Comment: It is a $1$-dimensional linear system of degree $2$ over a curve. By Riemann-Roch, since a smooth plane curve has genus $1$, every effective divisor of degree $2$ defines a $g^1_2$ on it. 
The classical term for such a object was "rational involution": in fact, every $g^1_2$ determines uniquely a degree $2$ morphism $C \to \mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: I'm assuming that the ground field is any algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $0$ (for instance $k= \mathbb{C})$. The chapter on curves in Hartshorne's book is a good introduction for all this stuff.

Comment: Fraser's paper seems to be exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  (It's actually easier for me to read than your description, since I'm not an algebraic geometer but I've read some synthetic projective geometry.)

Comment: Fraser's paper opens with a sketch of what appears to be a synthetic construction of the complex projective plane from the real one (I'm not sure what it would be in the general case, maybe the closure of a field under square roots?).  This looks very cool, but there are a lot of details left out; is it written down carefully anywhere?

Comment: Uhm, not that I'm aware of. But I'm not really an expert of synthetic projective geometry.

Comment: @MikeShulman, the synthetic approach to the complex plane was popular back in the day.  There are lots of accounts, e.g. [Hatton, Imaginary Geometry](https://archive.org/details/cu31924001523665/page/n5/mode/2up?view=theater).